# Adding a custom domain name with surge.sh

Tags: deployment, dns, ip, surge.sh

I'm a newbie in domain names, DNS etc.

I'm using [surge.sh](http://surge.sh/) for deploying my app. Now I want to add a custom domain, that I registered using [transIP](https://www.transip.nl/), and I can't get it working. I set the IP address to `45.55.110.124`, as they explain [here](https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-custom-domain). All together, I entered the following settings:

- Name: `*`
- TTL: `1 min`
- Type: `A`
- Address: `45.55.110.124`

And another one, exactly the same but then using name `@`:

- Name: `@`
- TTL: `1 min`
- Type: `A`
- Address: `45.55.110.124`

I created a test page that contains `hello domain`, inside a simple `html` file. Now, I deployed the page by moving to the folder that contains the html file and doing: `surge ./ mydomain.io`.

I waited over 5 minutes and nothing is changing. 
Now, my questions are:

- What am I doing wrong?
- My domain provider suggests that I also use an IPv6 address, but which one should I use for Surge?
- Why is there an option of setting TTL longer than 1 minute, who wants to wait longer before their deploy comes online?

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you want to use the `CNAME` instead of `A` record if possible. The reason for this is that their IP address can possibly change out from under you when infrastructure changes / updates / re-deploys. If possible, remove the `A` records and create `CNAME` records pointing to `na-west1.surge.sh.` instead.

Next, assuming that they want you to point to the same IP as `na-west1.surge.sh` resolves to, that IP is different from the documentation (possible even due to my previous explanation). You can `ping` the domain or use the `host` utility to get the current IP address:

```
$ host na-west1.surge.sh
na-west1.surge.sh has address 138.197.235.123
```

Armed with this information, try changing to `CNAME` records first. If this isn't possible, then use the updated IP address that you get from resolving the their `CNAME`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not there yet. My domain provider tells me that a CNAME is not possible for @. Which brings me to using this new IP address, `138.197.235.123`, but I applied this and it stil doesn't work. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It becomes harder to debug without having the real domain. When you `ping` your domain is it resolving to the correct IP now? Have you closed your browser to make sure DNS isn't cached?

Comment: When I ping my domain it gives:                     `mydomain.io has address 37.97.254.27
mydomain.io has IPv6 address 2a01:7c8:eb::95:170:78:135
mydomain.io mail is handled by 10 mx.transip.email.`

Comment: Whereas I set the IP address to `138.197.235.123`.

Comment: That would indicate the DNS is not updating properly or has not updated yet and may take some more time. This is more of an issue you should bring up with that provider at this point.

Comment: Yeah I was figuring so. Thanks anyway! I'll try to update if I have any news